# creación apk tomar fotos y ponerles el nombre que quiera android

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

alguien me podria asesorar para la creacion de:

> una app que tome una foto y despues se le pueda asignar el nombre que el usuario quiera ,

se oye sencilla pero lo mas que he podido es lo del codigo de abajo , y lo hace al revés, primero metes el nombre y despues captura la imagen , ademas de que tengo el problema de que mete "basura" a la hora de nombrar el nombre , por ejemplo si le digo que se llame `name1.jpg` lo hace mal y pone `name1969456547485634.jpg`.

Por mas que busco no se como pueda hacer la app ojala me puedan ayudar a corregir lo que ya llevo o consejos y links para aprender a hacer dicha app que por demas para expertos es sencilla pero soy novato saludos

PD: Me basé en este código: [Tutorial en youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYeVXGNG-b4)

```
package com.example.fotograpp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String imageFileName ="";
    Uri photoURI;

   public EditText caja;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        caja=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNombre);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1000);
        }

    }


    //Método para crear un nombre único de cada fotografia
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    public File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        // Create an image file name

        //String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageFileName="";
        imageFileName = caja.getText().toString();
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);

      //  mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    //Método para tomar foto y crear el archivo
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
      public void tomarFoto(View view) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {

                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: ¿Este es todo tu código, verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Si estas obtendo el nombre de imagen  "name1969456547485634.jpg", pero tu requieres "name1.jpg", lo que debes hacer es escribir dentro del `EditText` `caja` el valor "name1", para que pueda crear el archivo "name1.jpg":

```
imageFileName="";
imageFileName = caja.getText().toString();
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
```